# Find the probability $P(X=0|Y=1)$ in a ball drawing problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

A box contains $6$ Red, $2$ Green and $3$ White balls. Two balls are selected at random without replacement. Let $X$ be the number of selected Red balls and $Y$ be the number of selected Green balls. Then find $P(X=0|Y=1)$.

Here total $11$ balls in the box. Given $Y=1$, that is first ball drawn is known, which is Green. We have to find the probability that the second ball NOT to be Red.

The probability of getting a Green ball is $1/11$.

After that the remaining $10$ balls are there. To get NO Red ball (i.e., $X=0$), we have to choose from $4$ non-Red balls.

So required probability $\displaystyle =\frac{1}{11} \times \frac{4\choose 1}{10 \choose 1}=\frac{2}{55}.$

Is it correct? If not then where is my thinking wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question doesn't say that the **first** ball is green, only that $1$ ball is green.

So when two balls are drawn, knowing that one of them is green, we want to find the probability that in two draws, one is green and the other is white.

Thus $Pr = \Large\frac2{11}\frac3{10}+\frac 3{11}\frac2{10} = \frac6{55}$
__________________________-

**Added**

Using the combinatorial way, and writing out the full expression including red,

$Pr = \Large\frac{\binom60\binom21\binom31}{\binom{11}2}=\frac6{55}$

Comment: You have not considered the case that both balls could be Green. So to your probability above, you should add $\frac{2}{11}\frac{1}{10}$ and the result would be $\frac{8}{55}$.

Comment: @GaloisTH: If that was the intent of the question, it would have been written as  finding $P(X=0|Y \geq 1)$

Comment: Yes indeed you are correct. My bad.